# Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'EventosModel[]'

Tags: typescript

Hola tengo un proyecto en el cual consumo un API REST y quier que cada vez que consulte valla añadiendo elementos a la matriz pero tengo el siguiente error

> Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'EventosModel[]'

estos son mis códigos

este en mi modelo de interfaz

```
export class EventosModel {
Id: number;
Evento: number;
NombreGuardia: string;
NombreCliente: string;
NombreInstalacion: string;
FechaHora: string;
Turno: string;
evento: string;
icon: string
fecha: string;
hora: string;
background: any;
}
```

este es mi servicio para las peticiones HTTP

```
export class HttpService {

eventosURL = 'http://www.xxxx.cl:yyyy/zzz/aaaaa'

constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }


getEventos(imei: string){
  let url = `${this.eventosURL}/${imei}`
  return this.http.get<EventosModel[]>(url);
}
}
```

este es mi Home.ts

```
getEventos(dato: string, event?) {
this.httpService.getEventos(dato).subscribe(data => {
  this.eventos = this.eventos.push(...data) <--- error
})
```

}

ya me tiene de dolor de cabeza este problema alguien me podria decir que estoy haciendo mal

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: que viene en data?

Comment: Esto vine en data, editado en el post

Answer (score 0):

Espero que, dos años y medio después de hecha tu pregunta, el tema esté resuelto. En caso contrario y por si otro usuario tiene la misma duda, tu problema está en que `Array.prototype.push` no devuelve el array resultante, sino el número de elementos después del push.

Supongamos que

```
this.eventos = [Evento1,Evento2,Evento3]
data = [Evento5,Evento6]
```

Al hacer

```
this.eventos = this.eventos.push(...data)
```

es lo mismo que si hicieras

```
this.eventos = 5
```

Cosa que podrías evitar invocando push sin reasignar (puesto que de por sí modifica el array original)

```
this.eventos.push(...data)
```

O bien reasignando a la salida de `Array.prototype.concat` (que devuelve un array nuevo)

```
this.eventos = this.eventos.concat(data)
```